# Added Button does not show on UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a viewcontroller on the fly and set its view and title bar. Things seems to work just fine. But when I try to set the left button or right button of the navigation bar, they just do not show up. what am I doing wrong?

```
   UIWebView *tempWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [tempWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someurl"]]];

    UIViewController* tempViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    tempViewController.view = tempWebView;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tempViewController];

    UIBarButtonItem* closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
    navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;


    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;
```

to

```
tempViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;
```

The `navigationItem` appearance is handled by the view which is being presented by the nav controller, so if you set it on the `UINavigationController` but not on the `rootViewController`, it gets overridden when you push it the first time.

Comment: This helped as I used the ParentViewController to set the leftbarbutton

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the navigationItem of tempViewController, not the navigationController.